# Pydantic non-default argument follows default argument

Tags: python, pydantic

I don't understand why the code:

```
from typing import Optional
from pydantic import Field
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Klass:
    field1: str = Field(min_length=1)
    field2: str = Field(min_length=1)
    field3: Optional[str]
```

throws the error:

`TypeError: non-default argument 'field3' follows default argument`

if by default `Field` `default` kwarg is `PydanticUndefined`. Why are `field1` and `field2` default arguments?

I'm using python 3.8 and pydantic 2.6

I tried `field3: Optional[str] = Field(...)` and it works. I expected the code block above to work because all fields are required and none has default values.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question of *why*, but I suspect `field3: Optional[str] = None` will give you the behavior I think you're seeking.

Comment: This seems to be a flaw in the pydantic APIs.  Stdlib dataclass / field does not have this issue.

Comment: `Optional[str]` doesn't mean that the parameter can be left out and it will get a default value. It's a a required parameter but its value can be a string or `None`.

Comment: In fact, I intended to have two required fields (`field1` and `field2`) that must have at least one character, and a third ( `field3`) required field that can also `None` or `str`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR

- `field3` is a required argument with type `Optional[str]`, not an optional argument, because you didn't assign anything to `field3` in the class definition.
- `field1` and `field2` are *technically* optional, because the `Field` object you assign to each provides a default of `PydanticUndefined`. That value, though,
  causes a validation error at runtime if you don't supply another argument in its place.

---

The `dataclass` decorator is constructing a `def` statement to define your class's `__init__` method that looks something like

```
def __init__(self, field1=PydanticUndefined, field2=PydanticUndefined, field3):
    ...
```

The constructed statement is then `exec`ed, which is why you get the error about a non-default argument when the class is defined, rather than when you try to instantiate the class.

To make `field3` optional, you have to provide a default value.

```
field3: Optional[str] = None
```

This makes the defined statement something like

```
def __init__(self, field1=PydanticUndefined, field2=PydanticUndefined, field3=None):
   ...
```

---

You can't (as far as I know) make `field1` or `field2` truly required; the `PydanticUndefined` value just causes `__init__` to raise a `ValidationError` rather than a `TypeError` if no explicit
argument is passed.

```
>>> Klass()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/chepner/py311/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_dataclasses.py", line 134, in __init__
    s.__pydantic_validator__.validate_python(ArgsKwargs(args, kwargs), self_instance=s)
pydantic_core._pydantic_core.ValidationError: 2 validation errors for Klass
field1
  Field required [type=missing, input_value=ArgsKwargs(()), input_type=ArgsKwargs]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
field2
  Field required [type=missing, input_value=ArgsKwargs(()), input_type=ArgsKwargs]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.5/v/missing
```

I haven't dug into the source to see *exactly* how that happens, but I assume it's something resembling

```
def __init__(self, field1=PydanticUndefined, ...):
    if field1 is PydanticUndefined:
        # prepare ValidationError exception
    if field2 is PydanticUndefined:
        # prepare ValidationError exception
    if <ValidationError needs to be raised>:
        raise ValidationError(...)
```

If desired, you can provide "real" default values for `field1` and `field2` by adding the `default` keyword argument to `Field`.

Answer (score 1):

This is not about pydantic, it is python dataclasses error.
To fix error you need just move `field3` on top of `field1` and `field2`

This happens because on runtime of dataclasses they are trying to initialize like `__init__` in usual classes, dataclass tries to get it's fields one by one. As we know we can not set position args after keyword. Here we have the same situation.

Comment: Make sure we don't have fields without defaults following fields with defaults.  This actually would be caught when exec-ing the function source code, but catching it here gives a better error message, and future-proofs us in case we build up the function using ast.
This is comment on ```init_fn``` func in dataclasses.py file of python